# Если запрос был не корректным то не получается получить поток ввода

Tags: java, https

Если запрос корректный, то все хорошо, но если какой параметр с ошибкой, то когда пытаюсь вытянуть InputStream - ловлю exception. При том, что Postman прекрасно выводит тело ответа даже если запрос некорректен. Подскажите как можно считать ответ?

```
public String post(String address, String request) {
    String response = "";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(address);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(request);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("HttpsRequestHandler error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

ошибка - IOException

Comment: `ловлю exception` -- какой?

Comment: @post_zeew IOException

Comment: Стек-трейс покажите.

Answer (score 1):

Для ошибок отдельный поток:

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
InputStream errorStream = con.getErrorStream();
```

Делается по-разному, можно так:

```
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == 200){
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
} else {
    InputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
}
```

Можно так:

```
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
try {
    //...
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    //...

} catch (IOException e) {
    InputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
    //...
    logger.error("HttpsRequestHandler error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
}
```

Можно ещё как-нибудь как вам угодно.